# field in interface[golang]?

Tags: go

is there any solution to force **struct** have specific *property*(defined in **interface**)?
or define a property(attribute,field) in interface?.
as i see interface is always accept method not property?. (`https://gobyexample.com/interfaces`)

```golang
type geo interface {
    PrintType()
    typ string//not function , but field
}
type circle struct {
    typ string
}

func (c circle) PrintType() {
    fmt.Println(c.typ)
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfaces are about methods only, not properties, because interfaces are about behavior. So there is no way to force a struct to have something. Rather the  preferred method is to have an accessor to that member.